# Can not open project in redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

When I'm opening project I see `500 Internal error`

and in log file i can see the next info:

```
Started GET "/redmine/projects/xxx" for IP at Mon Apr 01 21:07:24 +0300 2013
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"xxx"}
  Current user: user_id (id=1)
  Rendered projects/show.html.erb within layouts/base (41.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 83ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `project_calendar_path' for #<#<Class:0xb4fb34ac>:0xb4f447c8>):
    52:     <p>
    53:       <%= link_to l(:label_issue_view_all), project_issues_path(@project, :set_filter => 1) %>
    54:       <% if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_calendar, @project, :global => true) %>
    55:         | <%= link_to l(:label_calendar), project_calendar_path(@project) %>
    56:       <% end %>
    57:       <% if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_gantt, @project, :global => true) %>
    58:         | <%= link_to l(:label_gantt), project_gantt_path(@project) %>
  app/views/projects/show.html.erb:55:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__145812006__629340778'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:165:in `show'
```

Beofre last upgrade there was no such problems :( What do I mean when I'm saying upgrade ? I'm using `apt-get upgrade` on my Ubuntu 12.04 server.

This is what was upgraded last time

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main redmine-sqlite all 2.3.0+dfsg1-6~precise+1 [12.5 kB]        
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main redmine-mysql all 2.3.0+dfsg1-6~precise+1 [12.5 kB]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-rails-3.2 all 3.2.13-1~precise+1 [3,378 B]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-railties-3.2 all 3.2.13-2~precise+1 [127 kB]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-actionmailer-3.2 all 3.2.13-1~precise+1 [22.2 kB]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-activeresource-3.2 all 3.2.13-1~precise+1 [38.3 kB]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-actionpack-3.2 all 3.2.13-2~precise+1 [297 kB]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-activerecord-3.2 all 3.2.13-2~precise+1 [300 kB]
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-activemodel-3.2 all 3.2.13-1~precise+1 [45.5 kB]              
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-activesupport-3.2 all 3.2.13-1~precise+1 [296 kB]             
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main ruby-rack-openid all 1.3.1-1~precise+2 [5,970 B]                   
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main redmine all 2.3.0+dfsg1-6~precise+1 [4,250 kB]
```

I don't know ruby, so I don't know how to fix it at all :(

Comment: I would really stay away from installing anything regarding rails with PPA's. Allocate some time and install RVM, it will save you many headaches in the future.

Comment: @AndrewWei Sorry I don't understand what is it RVM and how can I start use it ? could you please provide more information ? thanks

Comment: @AndrewWei and most important how could I get rid from current situation ?

Comment: Your using PPA's to install Rails and gems.... don't. Remove it all. Change directory into where your Rails project is, and always use "bundle install" to install the gems.

Comment: The only thing you need from "Ubuntu" is: ruby and sqlite. Let ruby worry about installing all the gems.

Comment: This guide should help you a lot: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: @AndrewWei thanks for tutorial, but about my situation should I remove all packagies from that list ? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017985/Screenshots/1u.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution, everything what should I do is

`rm -rf /var/cache/redmine/default/*`

and restart redmine

P.S. Thanks to package maintainer

Comment: hi I have the same problem, but it does not helped... I do not have this folder.